# Does Plone 3.3.6 have all the recent security hot fixes included?

Tags: security, plone

We recently upgraded to Plone 3.3.6 from 3.3.5.  Being paranoid I have left in the 3 recent hot fixes
Products.PloneHotfix20110720, Products.PloneHotfix20110531 and Products.Zope_Hotfix_20110622 in our buildout.

Does anyone know if Plone 3.3.6 as defined by http://dist.plone.org/release/3.3.6/versions.cfg contains all or some of these hotfixes?

Answer (score 0):

If you google names of hotfixes, you will find pypi page saying to which versions of Plone the fix applies. Normally Plone bugfix release is made withing 2 weeks.

Comment: The security advisories say Plone <= 3.3.5 but the release notes for Plone 3.3.6 don't mention the fixes